# Angular @Input() not binding and not working in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a master template with a component like this:

```
   <h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>]
```

The Master component is like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  public selectedHero: Hero;

  heroes: Hero[];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {

    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
        .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }
}
```

The Master template is getting data from a service.

On clicking the master's element in list the Child details are displayed.

Using this in master:

```
 <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
[class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
(click)="onSelect(hero)">
```

and binding in to

```
<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>]
```

But I am getting this error in the console.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       at HeroDetailComponent.push../src/app/hero-detail/hero-detail.component.ts.HeroDetailComponent.ngOnInit
>   (hero-detail.component.ts:19)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22099)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23363)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23325)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23959)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23919)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HeroesComponent.html:10)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:23548)

My child component is like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-detail.component.css']
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() hero: Hero;

  heroes: Hero[];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {  }
  i: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.i = this.hero.name

    this.getHeroes();

  }
  getHeroes(): void {

    this.heroService.getHeroes(this.i)
      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

}
```

Please Note: I am using the following to bind:

```
@Input() hero: Hero; // in child component to parent template
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the ngOnChanges to check whether the input value is set

```
  ngOnChanges() {
    if(!this.hero) return null;
    this.i = this.hero.name

    this.getHeroes();

  }
```

Comment: There are many similar questions to this OP.  But this actually solves how we can get the data from API passed from the parent to the @input child property.  If you want to console.log the data - it will be undefined on ngOnInit.  This is the method (life cycle) where we need to do this - thanks! Perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

onInit, the `hero` may not be defined, its getting populated after the component has been initialized. You can try using

```
@Input() set hero (value) {
   if(value) {
      this.i = this.hero.name;
   }
}
```